# Autocomplete in a x-editable text field in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, x-editable

I'm not sure if this is even feasible, but I wanted to implement an autocomplete functionality inside x-editable field in my ASP.NET MVC application.

Not much code to paste here, but from the UI it looks like this:

[image]

In this input, when I start typing I would like to see suggestions of autocomplete, based on the data from the db (in this case those two numbers above).

Could anyone help with this? I'm quite fresh in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a typeheadjs that deals with this in x-editable.